# Implement shopping cart JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cart

here what I am trying to do is when a user clicks the + button function should get called, it looks for the cookie shopping_cart. Then it tries to find the JSON with key 'item_qty', which is key-value pair of all the items in the cart. But the cart is not updating, moreover when clicked on + button is showing Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

In browser console I am getting it as

"csrftoken=some_value; shopping_cart=None"

```
var updateCart = function (count) {
    $('#cart-info').val($('#cart-info').val() + count);
};



var item_add = function (item_slug) {
    var shopping_cart = JSON.parse($.cookie("shopping_cart"));
    var item_slug = item_slug;
    if(shopping_cart.hasOwnProperty('item_qty')){
        item_qty_dict = shopping_cart['item_qty'];
        if(item_qty_dict.hasOwnProperty(item_slug)){
            var count_pre = item_qty_dict[item_slug];
            item_qty_dict[item_slug] = count_pre + 1;
        }
        else {
            item_qty_dict[item_slug] = 1;
            shopping_cart['item_qty'] = item_qty_dict;
        }
    }
    else {
        shopping_cart = {}
        shopping_cart['item_qty'] = {item_slug: 1};
    }
    $.cookie("shopping_cart", JSON.stringify(shopping_cart));
    var temp= $.cookie('shopping_cart')
    console.log(JSON.parse(temp));
};


var buttonPlus = $(".cart-qty-plus");

var incrementPlus = buttonPlus.click(function () {
    var $n = $(this)
        .parent(".qnty_chngr")
        .find(".qty");
    $n.val(Number($n.val()) + 1);
    var product_slug = $(this).parent(".qnty_chngr").siblings('.product-slug').val();
    console.log(product_slug);
    updateCart(1);
    item_add(product_slug);
});
```

HTML:

```
                        <div class="qnty_chngr">
                                    <button class="cart-qty-plus" type="button" value="+">+</button>
                                    <input type="text" name="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" class="input-text qty"/>
                                    <button class="cart-qty-minus" type="button" value="-" title="Add less quantity">-</button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" class="product-slug" name="product_slug" value="{{ medicine.slug }}">
                        <div class="add_to_cart">
                            <button  class="add_to_cart_txt" value="10"><span class="AddInfoBtn">Add </span></button>

                        </div>,
```

Comment: Any reason why you prefer `cookie` over `localStorage`? The output you are showing is what exactly? I don't see anywhere where you are adding 'None' to the shopping cart. How do you handle an empty cart?

Comment: what plugin you use for $.cookie ?
you might try $.cookie.json = true; to be able to store json in it

Answer (score 0):

Seems in your cookie there is no valid JSON. `None` is not valid, it should be `"None"` (with quotes). Remove the cookie before testing.

Also if possible try using this library which works the way you expected.

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie